# Handling gestures and swiping using Selenium and Appium using C#

Tags: c#, android, selenium, appium, gesture

I am writing my mobile testing using Appium and Selenium. I would like to automate gestures ans swipe and I've found no tutorial that addresses this using C#, all are in Java. This tutorial seems very OK as it addressed exactly what I want to do. Any C# equivalent of this: [Appium - How To Swipe Vertical And Horizontal In Android Automation](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/11/appium-how-to-swipe-vertical-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but worth exploring. Note that APpium 1.6 for iOS is now XCTest UI based so things are probably different - let me know if this helps

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17006/how-to-swipe-specific-element-using-appium